# Insert a WCF-SAP response message to a sql column of XML datatype

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I came across a scenario where I need to insert the WCF-SAP Response to a SQL staging table column which has XML datatype.

Is there any possibility to use BizTalk Map as I have other columns in the staging table to populate values.

Comment: Have you looked at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2c0f9799-9028-4546-8e4f-d5a1b221a353/example-using-sql-xml-type-field-in-orchestration-map-to-new-database-table?forum=biztalkgeneral

Answer (score 1):

This is solved by generating the schema in the assignment shape and inserted the XML into the SQL Column.

I faced some issues with Parent node accepts only Text where mine is a XML. That is also fixed when I used CDATA format.